# Usage of += operator with lambda operator

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code:

```
recognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
recognizer.Tapped += (args) =>
{
    // Send an OnSelect message to the focused object and its ancestors.
    if (FocusedObject != null)
    {
        FocusedObject.SendMessageUpwards("OnSelect", 
            SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }
};
```

I am working in a project for Unity and I am not that experienced with the syntax of this operation:

```
recognizer.Tapped += (args) =>
{
    // Send an OnSelect message to the focused object and its ancestors.
    if (FocusedObject != null)
    {
        FocusedObject.SendMessageUpwards("OnSelect", 
            SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }
```

I understand that `Tapped` is the event listener for taps. However, I don't understand the following things:

1) Why are they using a `+=` operator to add a lambda function. How can you add a lambda function like that? I've always used `+=` on primitive types.

2) Where does "args" come from?

3) When does that lambda function run?

Comment: This isn't adding a lambda function. `+=` is the syntax that adds an event listener. A lambda can be an event listener as long as it accepts the event's arguments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is Tapped an array? How does the += operator allow this? So it is adding a function to serve as an event listener.

Comment: It's an *event*, not an array. `+=` is the syntax used to add event listeners to events. [It's explained in the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/). That's not new syntax either, I think this was available since .NET 1.0

Comment: It's worth noting that you are mixing in two concepts. The first is event registration, the second is lambda expressions. It is not a requirement that events subscribe to lambda expressions, you could just as easily supply the name of a method whose signature matches what is expected, which in this specific case is a void method which takes a single argument in.

Comment: @Pablo - Did any of the answer below help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

**Why are they using a += operator to add a lambda function?**

The point here is **not** the lambda method but the **event** and registering delegates to it. It [overrloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators) the `+=` operator to subscribe more event listeners. The `Tapped` property is an event (*see links below*).

From the documentation of the `+=` operator:

> The += operator is also used to specify a method that will be called in response to an event; such methods are called event handlers. The use of the += operator in this context is referred to as subscribing to an event.

**Where does "args" come from?**

When the event triggers it triggers with an argument (In this specific case of the definition of `Tapped`. When it does it passes this argument to all the event listeners.

**When does that lambda function run?**

Whenever the event is triggered and causes all the listeners to be called. One of them will be this lambda method.

---

I suggest have a look at: [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)
and more in general about [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/index)

Also have a look at [Delegates and Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx) on MSDN and [+= operator with Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3356400/6400526)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is a lambda event listener. Rather than define it as a function like:

`function void myEvent(object o, EventArgs args){};
 recognizer.Tapped += myEvent;`

It's defined and assigned in the same place.

The reason that += is used is because you can have multiple event handlers assigned to the same event like so:

```
function void myEvent(object o, EventArgs args){};
function void yourEvent(object o, EventArgs args){};
recognizer.Tapped += myEvent;
recognizer.Tapped += yourEvent;
```

If you wanted to remove the assigned event you could use -= like so:

`recognizer.Tapped -= myEvent;`

The args are part of the event handler definition that is requited for all events